# Storage path is not part of public path Laravel

Tags: laravel

I wonder what is causing this error when I made a request to a Laravel project using Homestead.
This issue I think is related to storage link.

> Storage path `/home/vagrant/code/soso-api/storage/app` is not part of
> public path `/home/vagrant/code/soso-api/public`

Here's my filesystem.php

```
'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => public_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => public_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
        ],

    ],
```

in .env `FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=public`

I already tried

```
storage unlink
php artisan storage:link
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

but to no avail. Let me know if I miss something.

UPDATE:
changed `public_path` to `storage_path` doesn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => public_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

To:

```
'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL') . '/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

Comment: Not working for me.